# Singleton CDI @Inject null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, singleton, cdi, inject

I need to fire events from some ejb (Stateless and Singleton) using dependency injection. I do not use Spring, Guice etc. 
The problem is that I get NPE in one of beans when calling its method through getInstance(). Here is the code snippet:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ControllerStartStop {
    @Inject
    private Event<SomeWebMessage> webEvent; 

    public String startCircle(String passwordP, String passwordH) {
    .........
    String res = "some msg";
    webEvent.fire(new SomeWebMessage(res, 0));   // this works fine
    MainDay.getInstance().startDay();      // NullPointerException
```

Here is MainDay singleton:

```
@Singleton
public class MainDay {
    private static final MainDay mDay = new MainDay();
    public static MainDay getInstance() {   return mDay ;   }

    @Inject
    private Event<SomeWebMessage> webEvent; 

    public void startDay() {
        String s = new String("MainDay");
        webEvent.fire(new SomeWebMessage(s,0));   // NullPointerException
```

beans.xml is in META-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">

</beans>
```

There is no NPE when I fire event from a call of static method like MainDay.initDS() or when method startDay() is invoked by a Sheduler (*@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/10")*.
I have no idea what is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `@Singleton` means that the container (EJB or CDI, depends on which annotation it is) will manage the instance, i.e. *you* shouldn't create it yourself.

If you create the instance via `private static final MainDay mDay = new MainDay();` there won't be any injection by the container and thus `webEvent` will be null. Besides that the container won't know about that instance and using  `@Inject MainDay` somewhere else is very likely to produce another instance.

Thus just use inject (or lookups if you need to) directly:

```
class ControllerStartStop  {
  @Inject
  private MainDay mDay;

  ...
  public String startCircle(String passwordP, String passwordH) {
    ...
    String res = "some msg";
    webEvent.fire(new SomeWebMessage(res, 0)); 
    mDay.startDay();    
    ...
  }
```

> There is no NPE when I fire event from a call of static method like MainDay.initDS() or when method startDay() is invoked by a Sheduler (@Schedule(hour = "", minute = "", second = "/10")*. I have no idea what is the reason

Without knowing your code it's only a guess but I'd assume you're injecting `MainDay` here or using a CDI/JNDI lookup. Hence the container will create an instance if there is none and will inject the `Event` objects.

Answer (score 0):

**NPE 1:**

Shouldn't the targetted EJB `MainDay` "observe" the event and call its `startDay()` method?

```
public void onEvent(@Observes SomeWebMessage event) {
    // if (...)
        startDay();
}
```

So there is no need for a static `getInstance()` method.

**NPE 2:**

```
@Inject Event<SomeWebMessage> webEvent;
```

Dependency injection (DI) only works, if you do **not** manually call the constructor `new MainDay()` but inject instances of the wanted bean and let the DI container handle construction.

But with `@Observes` (javax.enterprise.event.Observes) you should be able to remove all the smelly `static` stuff anyway.

Comment: There is another one singleton that observes events fired in ControllerStartStop, MainDay and maybe one or two others:
`@Singleton
public class LongPollingNotifier {
 private final Queue<AsyncContext> peers = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<AsyncContext>();

@Asynchronous
 public void notifyPeers(@Observes SomeWebMessage swm) ...
`

Is this approach okay?

Comment: Yes you can have multiple independent observers.